# What software can monitoring audio on web pages

Tags: windows, audio, powershell, audio-streaming

I am looking for something that can simply monitoring audio status on web pages.

Lets say I have 4 tabs open on Chrome, each of the tabs is play some sort of audio from different source of streaming.

I want to have something just simply monitoring the status of those audios on the pages is playing or stopped, send me a notification if the audio is stopped.

Software, Scripts all OK, I am looking for some automation ideas instead of manually check them on a regular basis.

Comment: What have you tried. IMHO, this is a bit of a reach. PowerShell is not a GUI automation tool (it can do a little - but you are better off using other 3rdP - purpose built tools for that), and if you are sitting on a page playing vid/aud, then that site is using whatever player they decided on and thus you would need to know what that is and how to get out it.

Comment: I am researching for solution and so far found nothing. I want to know how windows volume mixer handling the audios from different sources on PC.

Comment: understood, but its a one to one system wide, AFAIK. Its the player in the Page that controls whether it's emitting any sound. There is no sperate ties to the Windows Mixer that I am aware of.